# JavaScript - Read a tamil word by character

Tags: javascript

i need to split a tamil word by character and print it using javascript.

Example :
Input  - ஆண்டாள்

output - ஆ
ண்
டா
ள்

can someone help me.

Comment: Does `"ஆண்டாள்".split("")` not do the trick?

Comment: Those aren’t split by character. Character split looks like `Array.from("ஆண்டாள்")` which yields `[ "ஆ", "ண", "்", "ட", "ா", "ள", "்" ]`. The [`Intl` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) probably has some relevant function for this.

Comment: @SamGomena str = "ஆண்டாள்";
var diacritics = {'\u0B82':true,'\u0BBE':true, '\u0BBF':true, '\u0BC0':true, '\u0BC1':true, '\u0BC2':true, '\u0BC6':true, '\u0BC7':true, '\u0BC8':true, '\u0BCA':true, '\u0BCB':true, '\u0BCC':true, '\u0BCD':true, '\u0BD7':true};         var str1 = str.split('');var Tamil = [];
for(var i = 0; i != str1.length; ++i){
var ch = str1[i];diacritics[ch] ?(Tamil[Tamil.length - 1] += ch) : Tamil.push(ch);}alert(Tamil);

Comment: this above code gave me the right output.. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

To take each individual character of the string and print it separately you’d want to do:

```
var myString = "ஆண்டாள்";
var myArray =[];
for(var i = 0; i<myString.length; i++){
    myArray.push(myString.charAt(i));
}

//Then print each character however you want example:
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

If you don't want each character saved in an array you can also do:

```
var myString = "ஆண்டாள்";

for(var i = 0; i<myString.length; i++){
    console.log(myString.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split tamil word by character using javascript...

Input - ஆண்டாள்

Output - ஆ,ண்,டா,ள் (array)... code works 100%

```
str = "ஆண்டாள்";
var diacritics = {'\u0B82':true,'\u0BBE':true, '\u0BBF':true, 
'\u0BC0':true, '\u0BC1':true, '\u0BC2':true, '\u0BC6':true, 
'\u0BC7':true, '\u0BC8':true, '\u0BCA':true, '\u0BCB':true, 
'\u0BCC':true, '\u0BCD':true, '\u0BD7':true};
var str1 = str.split('');
var Tamil = [];
for(var i = 0; i != str1.length; ++i){
var ch = str1[i];diacritics[ch] ?(Tamil[Tamil.length - 1] += 
ch) : Tamil.push(ch);
}
alert(Tamil);
```

Answer (score 0):

one more best way is below

```js
str = "ஆண்டாள்";
console.log(str.match(/[\u0b80-\u0bff][\u0bbe-\u0bcd\u0bd7]?/gi));//return ["ஆ", "ண்", "டா", "ள்"]
```